# Boost.Locale testing for particular backend

Tags: c++, boost, locale, compile-time

Is there a way to check (preferably at compile-time or at configure-time) whether the Boost.Locale library is compiled with support for particular backend (i.e. ICU)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost.Locale provides [this](http://www.boost.org/libs/locale/doc/html/classboost_1_1locale_1_1localization__backend__manager.html#a7bd336cf325b0ee284ab8a07813679c0):

```
std::vector<std::string> boost::locale::localization_backend_manager::get_all_backends() const
```

This will list all the backends available. E.g.,

```
localization_backend_manager lbm = localization_backend_manager::global();
auto s = lbm.get_all_backends();
for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [](string& x){ cout << x << endl; });
```

will print

```
icu
winapi
std
```

If Boost.Locale wasn't built with ICU support, it will list only the two last lines.

You can use this in a configure script and compile a .cpp that accepts a backend as a parameter and checks whether it is supported.